# SiteMapPath using MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, sitemap, asp.net-mvc-migration

I'm currently converting a project from Asp.Net MVC 2 to MVC 3 and I'm having trouble finding out how to do this...

```
asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server"
```

using Razor?

I've been playing with @SiteMap but other than getting the current node `@SiteMap.CurrentNode.ToString()` I'm having trouble finding a way to get the path.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, razor does not support the notion of controls. You need to use the good old webforms engine for this or wrap it in a html helper function.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that shows how to use the `@SiteMap` sytax in Razor View :)

[here](http://blogs.iis.net/carlosag/archive/2011/08/07/razor-migration-notes-1-moving-a-sitemappath-control-to-asp-net-web-pages.aspx)